# How to solve problem with missing argument

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code in file main.py:

```
from AD001 import PasswordTest      
for row in your_list:
            print(row[0], row[1])
            u = row[0]
            p = row[1]
            PasswordTest.test_login(u, p)
```

and this code call other file:

```
def test_login(self, u, p):
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    print("Login to AG")
```

but every time finish with error:

```
>   File "C:/selenium/AISG/IA/Users_role/main_reader.py", line 18, in
> <module>
>     PasswordTest.test_login(u, p) TypeError: test_login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p'
```

I do not understand why?

Comment: Can you share the code from `PasswordTest` file ?

Comment: what is the scope that `test_login` is defined in? Is it a class method? Is it inside `PasswordTest` file? You need to share this information. Right now as it seems, your function expects 3 arguments and you give it 2 so that's obviously wrong

Comment: You're calling it on the *class*, not on an *instance*.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create an instance of `PasswordTest` class in your main.py

```py
from AD001 import PasswordTest
p_test = PasswordTest()
for row in your_list:
    print(row[0], row[1])
    u = row[0]
    p = row[1]
    p_test.test_login(u, p)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you're calling is an instance method, meaning that it needs a class instance as the first argument. You are calling it directly on a class, so no instance is passed to it. There are two solutions:
- simply call `PasswordTest().test_login(u, p)`, instantiating this class, or
- make `test_login` a class method, via proper decorator, like this:

```py
@class_method
def test_login(cls, u, p):
    cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    print("Login to AG")
```

but you would need to change the `driver` field to be a class attribute.